# Error performing operations on array elements: "cannot move out of type"

Tags: arrays, rust

In the following example, I would like to add 2 elements within an array, there is a simple addition on 2 elements, declared inline, and accessed from an array.

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::fmt;

struct Vector(f64, f64);

impl Add for Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, _rhs: Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + _rhs.0,
               self.1 + _rhs.1)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Vector {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.0, self.1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let points: [Vector; 2] = [
        Vector(1.0, 1.0),
        Vector(5.0, 5.0),
    ];

    /* Adding from an array fails somehow: */

    // let v: Vector = Vector(1.0, 1.0) + Vector(5.0, 5.0);    // This works!

    let v: Vector = points[0] + points[1];                     // This fails!

    println!("Vector is {}\n", v);
}
```

For some reason `let v: Vector = points[0] + points[1];` gives the error:

```
main.rs:37:21: 37:30 error: cannot move out of type `[Vector; 2]`, a non-copy fixed-size array [E0508]
main.rs:37     let v: Vector = points[0] + points[1];                     // This fails!
```

How is it possible to avoid this error and perform operator overloading actions on array elements?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed to add support for adding `&Vector` types, then access the array elements as references.

This is a working example:

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::fmt;

struct Vector(f64, f64);

impl Add for Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, _rhs: Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + _rhs.0,
               self.1 + _rhs.1)
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'b Vector> for &'a Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, _rhs: &'b Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + _rhs.0,
               self.1 + _rhs.1)
    }
}


impl fmt::Display for Vector {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.0, self.1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let points: [Vector; 2] = [
        Vector(1.0, 1.0),
        Vector(5.0, 5.0),
    ];

    let v: Vector = &points[0] + &points[1];

    println!("Vector is {}\n", v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `Vector` tuple struct to derive from `Copy` and `Clone` traits. So the compiler can copy elements from array.

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Vector(f64, f64);

impl Add for Vector {
    type Output = Vector;

    fn add(self, _rhs: Vector) -> Vector {
        Vector(self.0 + _rhs.0,
               self.1 + _rhs.1)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Vector {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.0, self.1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let points: [Vector; 2] = [
        Vector(1.0, 1.0),
        Vector(5.0, 5.0),
    ];

    let v: Vector = points[0] + points[1];

    println!("Vector is {}\n", v);
}
```

Comment: Are there any down-sides to this? (unnecessary copying assuming `Vector` objects are much larger?) or are the copies generally optimized out?

Comment: @ideasman42 I'm a absolute Rust beginner too and now if I'm looking at your solution I think maybe it's better, because it's uses references and no copying is involved. Maybe we'll wait someone experienced to answer you comment :)